# How to have an object's scale be affected by proximity to empty?

Tags: animation, transforms, animation-nodes, geometry

I have a collection of cubes that are parented to a spinning circle. I would like the cubes to increase in scale as they pass through an empty and then shrink again so that the cubes at the front are bigger and highlighted more.

[image]

**Q:** How can I do this with animation nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [Object controller falloff](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/falloff/object_controller_falloff.html) or [Point Distance falloff](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/falloff/point_distance_falloff.html) to get proximity effect.
In your case you have animated cubes outside Animation Nodes. So we only care about scales of cube inside Animation nodes. Then here is how to do:

[image]

Or we can also build entire setup inside Animation nodes:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, Thank you!